# I can't access a function in another file

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jsx

I want to have a input that calls the function `handleChange` when something is typed (onChange). `handleChange` is in a parent file, so I added a prop `handleChange={this.handleChange}` to the component in the parent file.

```
function InviteForm(props) {
  const [nbInvites, setNbInvites] = useState(1);
  const onAddInviteClick = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setNbInvites(nbInvites + 1);
  };
  console.log(nbInvites);
  let inviteList = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < nbInvites; i++) {
    inviteList.push(<InviteInput key={i} />);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <form>{inviteList}</form>
      <AddInvitesButton onClick={onAddInviteClick} />
    </div>
  );
}

function InviteInput(props) {
  return (
    <li>
      <input
        className="form-input"
        type="email"
        placeholder="nom@exemple.com"
        name="invites"
        onChange={handleChange("invites")}
        required
      />
    </li>
  );
}
function Invites(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Title />
      <InviteForm />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Parent file

```
        return (
          <Invites
            nextStep={this.nextStep}
            handleChange={this.handleChange}
            values={values}
          />
        );
```

The error is :   Line 51:  'handleChange' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

--
Thanks you for your help

Comment: Please search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Comment: Did you import the external file into the file where you want to use the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not passing the props down to the `InputForm`:

```
function Invites(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Title />
      <InviteForm handleChange={props.handleChange}/> // Pass handleChange to the child component 
    </div>
  );
}

function InviteForm(props) {
  const [nbInvites, setNbInvites] = useState(1);
  const onAddInviteClick = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setNbInvites(nbInvites + 1);
  };
  console.log(nbInvites);
  let inviteList = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < nbInvites; i++) {
    inviteList.push(<InviteInput key={i} handleChange={props.handleChange}/>);  // Pass handleChange to the child component 
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <form>{inviteList}</form>
      <AddInvitesButton onClick={onAddInviteClick} />
    </div>
  );
}

function InviteInput(props) {
  return (
    <li>
      <input
        className="form-input"
        type="email"
        placeholder="nom@exemple.com"
        name="invites"
        onChange={props.handleChange("invites")} // Read it from the props
        required
      />
    </li>
  );
}
```

In this case, since you need to pass the props down on so many levels, it is generally recommended to look into using [React Context api](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or [Redux](https://redux.js.org/).

Comment: oh yes, I had tried but it didn't work, I just forgot the ```props``` before handleChange("invites"). Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

You've pass handleChange props to the inviteList component.

```
 let inviteList = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < nbInvites; i++) {
    inviteList.push(<InviteInput key={i} handleChange={props.handleChange} />);
  }
```

Comment: I just noticed @Clarity answered this.